# Identify files imported in k6 test script

Tags: performance-testing, k6

We are using k6 as performance test engine. In k6 JS script there are ways to import to the other files which could be used for the test. Is there any way that extract the dependent files which are used in k6 script?
For example:
My test file is k6-test.js and inside it I am importing a JSON file i.e test.json? Is there any way that I could get file name test.json as output?

Comment: Not that I know of. What are you doing with that information?

Comment: We have developed one tool which is a wrapper over k6. When developer comes in uploading a test script in tool we should automatically promt dependent files which are mentioned in test script.